# Is it possible to find-out whether given group is $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ or else?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, group-isomorphism

Suppose we are given two multiplication tables of two groups. one corresponds to $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ and other corresponds to $ \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. I know that these two groups are isomorphic. Is it possible to find out which table corresponds to $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ out of these two given tables?

If yes how otherwise state explicitly what other information is needed to differenitate these two table.

Comment: For your last question; the whole point of group theory is just to NOT differentiate between isomorphic groups, because it is not possible if the elements are not given. Isomorphism really is the best we can get. It really means that the groups are the same, we just named the elements differently.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$?

Comment: @quid from the way the question is formulated, in terms of given multiplication tables, it doesn't really matter what definition is being used.

Comment: @DerekHolt maybe so. I am still curious to know what OP means.

Comment: @ quid cyclic group of order 15.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549008/what-does-it-mean-when-two-groups-are-isomorphic/1549010#1549010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$|G|&gt;2$ implies $G$ has non trivial automorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8379/g2-implies-g-has-non-trivial-automorphism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to differentiate the two groups, up to isomorphism.

Since $\gcd(5, 3) = 1$, we know that

$$\mathbb Z_{5} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \cong \mathbb Z_{15}$$

The set of elements are ordered pairs in $$\mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_3 = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2),  (1, 0), (1, 1),  \ldots (2, 0), \ldots (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2)\}$$  You'd need to make a list  15 elements along the column headers, and the same along the row headers, just as you get when making a table for $\mathbb Z_{15}$. The element $(0,0)$ is the identity, and recall that the operation on $\mathbb Z_{5} \times \mathbb Z_{3}$ is component-wise addition, modulo 5 for the first term, mod 3 for the second term.

For example:  $(1, 3) + (2, 2) = (3_{\text{ mod }5}, 2_{\text{ mod }3}) = (3, 2).$

Every of the 15 elements in $\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_3$ can be mapped to a unique element in $\mathbb Z_{15}$.  So the Cayley tables will be identical, save for the name of each element.

Comment: There is an isomorphism (bijection) that sends each element $\beta \in \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_3$ to an element $\alpha \in \mathbb Z_{15}$

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot. *Precisely* because they are isomorphic.