# A weaker condition than the operation-preserving one, for a weaker result.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ and $\overline G$ be groups, and $f\colon G\to\overline G$ a bijection. Then:
$$\forall g,h\in G: f(gh) = f(g)f(h) \tag1$$
if and only if:
$$\mathfrak c=\psi_f\bar{\mathfrak c}f \tag2$$
where $\mathfrak c$ and $\bar{\mathfrak c}$ are Cayley's embedding of $G$ and $\overline G$ into $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ and $\operatorname{Sym}(\overline G)$, respectively, and $\psi_f\colon\operatorname{Sym}(\overline G)\to\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ is defined by $\sigma\mapsto f^{-1}\sigma f$.

**Question**. Is there any weaker (than $(1)$) condition on the bijection $f$, which ensures the weaker (than $(2)$) result:
$$\operatorname{im}(\mathfrak c)=\operatorname{im}(\psi_f\bar{\mathfrak c}f) \tag3$$
(here "$\operatorname{im}(\_)$" stands for "the image of")?

**Motivation**. Intuitively, I'd expect $(3)$ being sufficient to get $G$ and $\overline G$ "somehow isomorphic".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us prove that $(3)$ is equivalent to
$$\exists k\in\overline G,\forall g,h\in G:f(gh)=f(g)kf(h)\tag4$$

To begin with,
$$(3)\iff A_f=B_f$$
where $A_f$ and $B_f$ are the two following sets of maps from $G$ to $\overline G:$
$$A_f:=\{h\mapsto f(g)f(h)\mid g\in G\}=\{h\mapsto vf(h)\mid v\in\overline G\},$$$$B_f:=\{h\mapsto f(gh)\mid g\in G\}.$$

- If $A_f=B_f$ then $B_f\subset A_f,$ i.e.
  $$\forall g\in G,\exists v\in\overline G,\forall h\in G:f(gh)=vf(h),$$
  which is equivalent to
  $$\forall g\in G,\forall h\in G:f(gh)f(h)^{-1}=f(ge)f(e)^{-1}$$
  where $e$ denotes the identity element of $G.$

  Letting $k:=\left(f(e)\right)^{-1},$ this implies $(4).$
- Conversely, assume $(4).$ Then,
  $$\begin{align}B_f&=\{h\mapsto f(g)kf(h)\mid g\in G\}\\
  &=\{h\mapsto ukf(h)\mid u\in\overline G\}\\&=A_f,
  \end{align}$$
  which ends the proof.

**Edit**, to answer today's comment below:

Let us prove that if $f:G\to\overline G$ is a bijection satisfying $(4)$ then, there exists some $c\in G$ such that for every $\bar g,\bar h\in\overline G:$
$$f^{-1}(\bar g\bar h)=f^{-1}(\bar g)cf^{-1}(\bar h)$$
i.e.
$$\bar g\bar h=f\left(f^{-1}(\bar g)cf^{-1}(\bar h)\right),$$
which, according to $(4),$ is equivalent to
$$\bar g\bar h=\bar gkf(c)k\bar h.$$
The solution is $c=f^{-1}(k^{-2}).$ Note that it satisfies the dual identity $k=f(c^{-2}),$ since $f(c^{-2})=f(c^{-1})kf(c^{-1})=k,$ because (similarly to $k=\left(f(e)\right)^{-1}$ above) the property of $c$ makes it necessarily equal to $\left(f^{-1}(\bar e)\right)^{-1}$ where $\bar e$ is the identity element of $\overline G.$

Comment: As opposedly to true isomorphisms, the inverse of a bijection $f$
 with the property $(4)$
 does not fulfill the same property.

Comment: Ah ok, I had missed that, thanks. So, seemingly we can think of a "quasi-isomorphism" relation, say $G\approx \overline G$, between possibly non-isomorphic groups ($G\not\cong\overline G$)? I think I proved already that, e.g., still $C_4\not\approx K_4$, but perhaps other cases work.